# Build dictionary in python

Tags: python

Php is smart enough to allow me to do something like this when building an associative array...

```
while ($row = $mysql_result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $array[$row['ip']][$row['slot']] = '';
}
```

...There will be X number of IPs and X number of slots per IP. I can create new keys and additional associative arrays on the fly as needed.

Does python have a similar functionality? It doesn't appear I can do something similar like this when building a dictionary...

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
host_list = {}
for row in rows:
  host_list[row['ip']][row['slot']] = ''
```

...because I get something like this: KeyError: '192.168.1.101'

Do I have to do it like this where I keep having to check that the key exists and create it if it doesn't...

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
host_list = {}
for row in rows:
  if row['ip'] not in host_list.keys():
    host_list[row['ip']] = {}
  host_list[row['ip']][row['slot']] = ''
```

...or is there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get all mysql tuple result and convert to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315919/how-to-get-all-mysql-tuple-result-and-convert-to-json)

Comment: Your way is fine. You can also use a `defaultdict` or a `setdefault` method on a regular dict. Note, don't use `.keys()` to check if an key is in a dict, you can just use `some_key in some_dict`

Comment: What columns are you fetching with `cur.fetchall()`? I'm asking because the code can become a lot cleaner if you iterate `rows` with something like `for ip, slot in rows:` instead.

Comment: Agreed on cleanliness accdias, but I just wanted it to be clear and concise as to what was going on. To do something like you're talking about wouldn't I need to do something like this: ip = row['ip']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

hostlist = defaultdict(dict)
for row in rows:
  host_list[row['ip']][row['slot']] = ''
```

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing but you were faster. :-)

Comment: A follow-up to this regarding the same script. I'm doing something like this: data[ip][oid_label] = str(value) which works fine, but when I go another layer deeper and try to do something like this: data[ip][slot][oid_label] = str(value) I get a KeyError. Thoughts?